# Kotlin multiPlatform - throw custom throwable to iOS(Objective-C/Swift) in Kotlin multiPlatform

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

KMM code is throwing custom throwable but at iOS side it is received as NSError/Error Object only in completionHandler.

**KMM Code**

```
class Greetings {
    @Throws(Throwable::class)
    suspend fun updateData() {
        throw CustomError("This is the customised error msz",123)
    }
}

class CustomError(msz:String, code: Int): Throwable(message = msz)
```

**iOS Code**

```
Greetings().updateData { <#Error?#> in <#code#> }
```

As per the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-objc-interop.html#errors-and-exceptions) it is not possible to get the custom throwable at iOS side in completionHandler.

One thing I can do is I can return the CustomError object instead of throwing that from `updateData()` and can have it in completionHandler of iOS.

But i am looking for any better work around to achieve this

Comment: Have you considered returning Swift's `Result` type?

Comment: @lazarevzubov updateData() method is defined in kotlin that does not have idea of Result so can not return it from there.

Comment: You could declare your own `Result`, its implementation is extremely basic.

Comment: You'll want to write your own typed result that represents the error as an expected state. Throwing exceptions from Kotlin to Swift is definitely something that doesn't work out too great (in my experience).